# Redirect custom AuthenticationForm once authenticated - Django

Tags: django

Is it possible to redirect a user once they pass through the `confirm_login_allowed` of `AuthenticationForm`.

For example, I was trying to redirect the user in the forms by doing

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError('There was a problem with your login.', code='invalid_login')
        elif user.is_staff and not self.has_2fa():
            logger.info('is staff but does not have 2FA, redirecting to Authy account creator')
            return redirect('admin/authy_me/authenticatormodel/')
        elif user.is_staff and self.has_2fa():
            logger.info("is staff and 2FA enabled")
        elif not user.is_staff and not self.has_2fa():
            logger.info('is not staff and does not have 2FA')
```

or is `confirm_login_allowed` used only for validation error? if so is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. `confirm_login_allowed` cannot have any redirects, you would have to create a custom view and then do the redirects there.

for examples in `views.py`

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_staff and not has_2fa(request):
        logger.info('is staff but does not have 2FA, redirecting to Authy account creator')
        return redirect('admin/authy_me/authenticatormodel/')
    elif request.user.is_staff and has_2fa(request):
        logger.info("is staff and 2FA enabled")
    elif not request.user.is_staff and not has_2fa(request):
        logger.info('is not staff and does not have 2FA')

    defaults = {
        'authentication_form': LoginForm,
        'template_name': 'core/login.html',
    }

    return auth_login(request, **defaults)
```

and in `urls.py`, instead to importing `from django.contrib.auth.views import login` import `from app_name.views import login` then add

```
url(r'^login/?$', app_name.login, name="login")
```